# From program to complete project, what does a "real" Unix app require?

Tags: packaging

I'm finishing off a [small command-line BASIC interpreter](https://github.com/maurymarkowitz/RetroBASIC) for Unix. It currently consists of a dozen sources and headers, a makefile, test files and an Xcode project for working on the Mac. This is my first pure-CLI project.

Releasing an app on iOS is well documented, there are checklists of items you need to submit - the app itself, various materials that go in the App Store page like images and text, and so forth. There are also guides on the workflow of the process itself and how to get the word out.

What is the equivalent for Unix? There are dozens of package managers/app stores as well as any number of simpler download sites and I'm finding it difficult to get my head around it all. I tried Googling the topic, but the results are polluted by installer guides for individual products. The only cogent page I found was for Unix System V.

I am wondering if someone might point me in the direction of a guide that takes you through this process and also indicates what the *user* expectations are? I don't want to make a package but forget some "everyone knowns you need **this**" sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian has a “[How to be a good upstream guide](https://wiki.debian.org/UpstreamGuide)”, which contains lots of useful tips even if you’re not actually working on a package for Debian or any other distribution. The main considerations are:

- ship pristine source code, ideally with no build artifacts
- don’t include third-party dependencies
- choose a license, and ensure that choice is clear
- do actual releases
- include documentation (for extra bonus points, a man page)
- avoid hard-coded paths
- if you need to store user-specific configuration etc., follow [the XDG base directory specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)
- choose your dependencies carefully
- include a test suite (for extra bonus points, allow it to run using your program after it’s installed, not just in the build tree)
- pay attention to security

There are more detailed considerations when it comes to your build system itself; one pain point I often run into is the use of specific flags, or ignoring well-known flags (`CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` etc.).

Comment: Fantastic post SK! Item #2 was the primary concern of my last set of changes. Item 5 on your list, I included what seems like a reasonable readme, is it much effort to turn that into a man page and install it on the user machine?

Comment: Writing your first man page always takes more effort than.expected, even if you have the source material ;-). A man page doesn’t have the same purpose as a README; in your case, you’d only keep the “Running” and “Errata” sections. I can take care of it if you want (see also the two PRs I opened yesterday).